# How to increase Visual Studio debug session telemetry limit of 250 events?

Tags: visual-studio, limit, local, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-debugging

I'm looking at Application Insights telemetry in Visual Studio local debug session and I've hit "last 250 events" limit. Is there any way to increase it?

[image: VS limit of number of events in debug sessiom]

**Update**: After some deliberation and help from community, we made a TelemetryProcessor that captures copy of TelemetryItems to file. This is a work-around for '250 telemetry items' limit, but it effectively solves the problem of not loosing telemetry during local debug sessions. More details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914390/how-to-save-copy-of-Application-Insights-telemetry-into-a-file-locally-on-the-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back a *long long time ago* when I worked on this, there was a registry value  `LocalDebugLimit` under the registry key `AppInsightsGettingStarted` inside VS's User hive that you could set to override this behavior.

Since we did that work, VS has changed how/where it stores registry info, so you'll have to dig into how to do that now, i think it has separate tools than just standard RegEdit?

If you were to use something like process monitor you could probably watch for the calls to look in the registry to see if something similar still exists?

This is possibly very out of date information, sorry!