# How to save copy of Application Insights telemetry into a file locally (on the machine which produced it)?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, local, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP .NET CORE app with application insights installed. How do I configure it to save a copy of telemetry into a local file (in addition to sending to cloud)?

I'm not looking for Continuous Export feature (AFAIU, it has to go through portal first). I'm looking for a scenario like "save 100% of telemetry locally, but send a sampled subset to Azure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way - add a [TelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) which saves a telemetry item locally and calls `this.Next.Process(item)`.

Alternatively you can achieve the same with [TelemetrySink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetrysink?view=azure-dotnet).

The first approach is probably easier.

To save them in text representation you can use `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.JsonSerializer.Serialize` (takes `IEnumerable<ITelemetry> telemetryItems`). This will return a byte array. I guess calling `Deserialize` on that byte array should give you string representation of json.

Comment: I tried the Processor route initially, but it would take some work to properly serialize every type of telemetry it can receive. AFAICS, I shouldt just convert it to Json, since that would grab contents of its context variable. Would you know of an existing solution or method to turn arbitrary telemetry item into a flat log line?

Comment: Application Insights has a function for this (added as a part of answer). We use it in one scenario to serialize to byte array. I guess Deserialize should give you string.